# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager only on Build APK

Tags: java, android

I have searched a lot here and on Google and found no answer that solved my problem. When i run my app from instant run, it works perfectly. When i generate my release APK, it doesn't open and show this error only on Lollipop builds (5.0 and 5.1, works fine on 6.0>):

```
08-15 11:31:47.689 2605-2605/br.com.turbi.turbi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: br.com.turbi.turbi, PID: 2605
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
      at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.open(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:54)
      at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.getInstance(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:70)
      at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:289)
      at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:231)
      at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.turbi.turbi-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.turbi.turbi-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.open(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:54) 
      at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.getInstance(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:70) 
      at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:289) 
      at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:231) 
      at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 20 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

In my Gradle file, i have turned minifyEnabled to false already :

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies(i added the android-support-v4.jar as a external lib, but it did not solve the problem either):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.0'
compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile 'com.vicmikhailau:MaskedEditText:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
/** * Glide  ***/
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

}

Hope someone can help me, already spent a lot of time and effort on this problem and cant find a solution. Thanks on advance!

Edit:

After Puneet solution, i started getting the below error when running the app, any clues? :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: br.com.turbi.turbi, PID: 28785
                                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat;
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:734)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:367)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                    at br.com.turbi.turbi.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:26)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.turbi.turbi-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.turbi.turbi-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:734) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:367) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
                                                                    at br.com.turbi.turbi.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:26) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 30 more
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced similar problem.

This is because of the instant run feature is enabled. Just disable it, clean the project then build the project. Now generate release Apk. It will work.

May be Android Studio is not including all files in Apk, when we use the instant run to fasten the process.

On PC:

> Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy -->
>   Instant run.

On Mac:

> Android Studio --> Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment -->
>   Instant Run.

Comment: Thanks, doing what you suggest stoped the  problem i related on the topic, but now i am having this:Process: br.com.turbi.turbi, PID: 28785                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat; even when running from the Android Studio. Any clues?

Comment: @ArthurTavais open another question, referencing this one.

Comment: send me the link for that question , I am unable to get that question

Comment: @ArthurTavais You need to include the appcompat-v7 library and possibly the design support library, which would also require the appcompat library.

Answer (score 14):

This issue is because third party lib is still using v4 support lib.
To fix this issue add the following in your **gradle.properties**

```
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was to add the dependency

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:<compileSdkVersion>.x.x"
```

in my gradle dependencies.

You can check the version according to your compileSdkVersion [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-v4).

From sdk version 29, you need to convert your project to androidx and use the new [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-v4)

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue after migrating to **AndroidX**.

I have added the following dependency.

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

With latest Android Studio 2021.3.1 building to compileSdk 33, I had to do both of above to resolve the runtime Exception.

So add to build.gradle (app) dependencies:

> implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"

And add to gradle.properties:

> android.enableJetifier=true